# Views not working with Simpletest

Tags: views, testing

I have just started using the Simpletest module for Drupal 7.  I am trying to use the drupalGet function to pull a URL.  The URL is a views module URL.  I am able to pull other pages using the function.  But none of my views are working.

I think I am missing some small piece here.  Any suggestions please.